# How to use Container in find operation in Jemmy library?

Tags: java, jemmy

Can anyone give explanation and an example of `Container` usage?

E.g. I am trying to find `JProgressBar`, and all the find method has `Container` as the first param.:

```
JProgressBar pb = JProgressBarOperator.findJProgressBar([Container cont]);
```

I supposed that `JFrame` or `JDialog` etc. could be used (cast) as Container, but it is not. So what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get `Container` of parent element by `.getContentPane()`:

```
JFrameOperator mf = new JFrameOperator("Main Frame");
JDialogOperator jd = new JDialogOperator(mf, ""); // dialog that contains JProgressBar has no name
JProgressBar pb = JProgressBarOperator.findJProgressBar(jd.getContentPane());
```